# Recorrer una lista agregando a otra los elementos menores al que recibo por parámetro

Tags: java, arraylist

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
quiero saber como recorro la lista y le agrego las condiciones para luego agregar los items a otra lista

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrar algo de lo que ya tienes hecho? como para tener un punto inicial para poder ayudarte.

Answer (score 0):

no quiero que nadie me haga nada gratis solo quiero ayuda! si no quieren hacerlo no estan obligados! y perdon por no poner mi codigo! es este:

public List consultarItemsFaltantes(int cantidadMaxima) {
        List resultado = new ArrayList();

```
    for (ItemStock lista : this.items) {
        if (lista.getCantidad() < cantidadMaxima) {
            resultado.add(lista);
        }
    }
    // otro modo

    for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
        if (items.get(i).getCantidad() < cantidadMaxima) {
            resultado.add(items.get(i));
        }
    }
    return resultado;

}
```

puse de dos modos por que no se si alguno de ambos sea el correcto! o si ambos lo son cual es el mas prolijo! Gracias y perdón por desconocer las reglas de como se trabaja en este ambiente! nadie quiere hacerlos trabajar gratis! Disculpes si les hice perder valioso tiempo!

Comment: Por lo que veo los 2 modos son correctos, aunque supongo que a la vista queda más elegante y fácil de entender el primero, el que se recorre con un for each mejorado. 
Deberías editar la pregunta, mejorarla con el código que has puesto ahora y si crees que el compañero que te ayudó lo hizo correctamente, pues puedes dárselo por bueno por ejemplo. Y tranquilo que se te ayuda con gusto. Saludos!

Answer (score -2):

En este ejemplo trabajo con una lista de enteros, pero puedes modificarlo para el tipo de lista de necesites, y trabaje con un dato quemado 5, pero podría ser introducido por teclado. Espero te ayude.

```
import java.util.*;
public class recorridoLista
{
static List ItemStock;

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        ItemStock = new ArrayList();
        ItemStock.add(5);
        ItemStock.add(6);
        ItemStock.add(4);
        ItemStock.add(7);
        ItemStock.add(4);
        ItemStock.add(2);
        ItemStock.add(1);
```

`Iterator iter = ItemStock.iterator();
    System.out.print("<ItemStock original> ");
    while (iter.hasNext()){
        System.out.print(iter.next());
    }
    System.out.print("\n<ItemStock items Menores> ");           
    int cantidadMaxima=5; //Puede ser cualquier parametro
    List<Integer> resultado = cunsultarItemsFaltantes(cantidadMaxima);  //menores a 5
    Iterator iter2 = resultado.iterator();
    while (iter2.hasNext()){
        System.out.print(iter2.next());
    }
 }
 public  static List<Integer> cunsultarItemsFaltantes(int cantidadMaxima){
     List<Integer> aux = new ArrayList<Integer>();  
     for(Integer val : ItemStock)
     {
         if(val<cantidadMaxima){
             aux.add(val); //Nueva lista
         }              
     }    
    return aux;
 }}`

Comment: Hay que ayudar siempre y cuando el OP lo haya intentado. No debemos hacerle los deberes. Saludos

Comment: Concuerdo con @DiegoLoL, En casos como estos no deberíamos ponernos a hacer deberes a nadie. A preguntas como estas serian mas aconsejadas respuestas con ejemplos simples o links con las bases por las cuales puede empezar a hacerlo pero no todo el ejercicio de clase terminado. Tanto para ayudar al usuario como para prevenir trabajos gratuitos

Comment: Es una mala practica el solo responder con código, debes explicar el código o adjuntar la documentación de algunas partes del mismo.